# A method to create a test using a Jar

Tags: java, testing, jar

Probleme :

I have an PLM integration code which means that I have client/server classes. So recently I have done a customization in a class (server classes) to send a message to my application (client). This customization is just a JSON object that contains a String message and ArrayList which can be added or not (its up to the client to choose). So I need to test this customization in futur versions but those changes are not in the class meaning can't be in other version (has to be added manually if client wants to).

My question is : is it possible to create a test using a Jar that simplify for me the task without having to add the code manually ? Or can I have a copy of this class to test it but without doing any modification ?

Comment: You are probably using git ? Create a new branch for this feature and at a later state you can merge the feature into the main artefact.

Comment: @PeterMmm I will create another package that contains this class, but I need to update the existing jar with this class I posted a new question for this